# VB.NET Subclass of class containing list collection of subclassed items

Tags: vb.net, list, subclass, generic-list

Consider a class named Fruit and a class named FruitStand which contains a generic List of Fruit and exposes a property (Contents) to obtain the List of Fruit for the pupose of iterating the Fruit in the class.

Now I want to create a class Apple that is a subclass of Fruit and I want a class called AppleCart that is a subclass of FruitStand.  The contents of the generic List in AppleCart will only ever contain intances of the Apple class. What I want is to be able to have a consumer of AppleCart not have to cast the elements returned by the Contents property to Apple from Fruit.

I am hoping this is something simple that I am just having a mental block over.

Comment: If the AppleCart can only contain Apples, why would anyone have to cast it?

Comment: Rather than AppleCart inheriting from FruitStand, maybe an interface (eg `IFruitVendor(of T)`) would do what you want.

Comment: Becuase the SuperClass (FruitStand) returns a List of Fruit as opposed to a List of Apple.  So a consumer would have to cast the Fruit returned from the enumerator to Apple to access the properties specific to Apple.   The Apple Cart only contains Apples because it ensures only Apples are added to the List.

Comment: I thought of something like IFruitVendor but I want the logic of FruitStand to be part of the class and not need to be replicated in both classes.  The issue is AppleCart is still a FruitStand just with added functionality - not different functionality.

Comment: AppleCart would only return Fruit if it did not override/Overload the method to return items.  They apparently get into the Fruit bin via an AppleCart method, if they come out the same way, they are Apples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use generics.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim cart As New AppleCart

    cart.Fruits.Add(New Apple)

End Sub

Class FruitStand(Of T As Fruit)

    Public Property Fruits As List(Of T)

End Class

Class Fruit

End Class

Class AppleCart
    Inherits FruitStand(Of Apple)

End Class

Class Apple
    Inherits Fruit

End Class
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic constraint on the `FruitStand` class, which forces a derived class to specify a class which derives from `Fruit` in its declaration

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ac As New AppleCart({New Apple(), New Apple()})
    For Each a In ac.Fruits
        a.Rot() ' prints "The apple is rotten!"
    Next
    Console.Read()
End Sub

Public Class Fruit
    Public Overridable Sub Rot()
        Console.WriteLine("The fruit is rotten!")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Apple
    Inherits Fruit
    Public Overrides Sub Rot()
        Console.WriteLine("The apple is rotten!")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FruitStand(Of T As Fruit)
    Private _fruits As List(Of T)
    Public ReadOnly Property Fruits As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Get
            Return _fruits
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(fruits As IEnumerable(Of T))
        _fruits = fruits.ToList()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class AppleCart
    Inherits FruitStand(Of Apple)
    Public Sub New(fruits As IEnumerable(Of Apple))
        MyBase.New(fruits)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing 3 options: you either make your `FruitStand` generic like so:

```
Class FruitStand(Of TFruit As Fruit)
  Public ReadOnly Property Contents As List(Of TFruit)
End Class

NotInheritable Class AppleCart
  Inherits FruitStand(Of Apple)
End Class
```

Or you sever the relationship between `FruitStand` and `AppleCart` and instead derive them both from the same, newly extracted base class (I think this is the neatest option):

```
MustInherit Class FruitStandBase(Of TFruit As Fruit)
  Public ReadOnly Property Contents As List(Of TFruit)
End Class

NotInheritable Class FruitStand
  Inherits FruitStandBase(Of Fruit)
End Class

NotInheritable Class AppleCart
  Inherits FruitStandBase(Of Apple)
End Class
```

In both cases I've sealed the derived `AppleCart` as no type that derives from it will be able to override the type of `TFruit`. At that point in the hierarchy the type of `Contents` is closed.

Finally, you may be able to use shadowing to change the meaning of `Contents` in the more derived types. The catch is: you have to use a covariant collection for your base type's `Contents` property (which means using a read-only interface such as `IReadOnlyList(Of Fruit)` or an array - either way you're losing the ability to add or remove elements):

```
Class FruitStand

  Public ReadOnly Property Contents As IReadOnlyList(Of Fruit)

  Public Sub New()
    Me.New(New List(Of Fruit))
  End Sub

  Protected Sub New(contents As IReadOnlyList(Of Fruit))
    Me.Contents = contents
  End Sub

End Class

Class AppleCart
  Inherits FruitStand

  Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Contents As IReadOnlyList(Of Apple)
    Get
      Return CType(MyBase.Contents, IReadOnlyList(Of Apple))
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(New List(Of Apple))
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: All three of these approaches have merit.  For my purposes the simplest approach (Making the FruitStand generic) was sufficient as stated in the_lotus answer.